# XML Python Parsing

Tags: python, xml

I am new to trying to parse XML with python I have provided the xml below. I am need to get the following data Instrmt afg="AG" and Qty Typ="FIN" QTYL="149" I need the AG and the 149.

I have tried the following:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse(test.xml)

batch = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Batch')[0]

rpt = batch.getElementsByTagName('PosRpt')

for ag in rpt:
    sym = ag.getElementsByTagName('Instrmt')
    print(sym)
```

When I do this I get a DOM object and not sure how to get the results I am trying for.

```
- <XML r="20030517" s="20042209" v="4.4" xr="FIA" xv="1">
- <Batch>
- <PosRpt RptID="175" BizDt="2013-01-03" ReqTyp="0" >
  <Pty ID="Ade" R="21" /> 
- <Pty ID="000" R="4">
  <Sub ID="F" Typ="29" /> 
  </Pty>
  <Instrmt afg="AG" ID="AG" Src="8" CFI="FFI" MMY="2013" Matf="2013"/> 
  <Qty Typ="AOD" QTYL="134" QTYS="0" /> 
  <Qty Typ="FIN" QTYL="149" QTYS="0" /> 
  <Amt Typ="FMTM" Amt="155065.44" /> 
  </PosRpt>
  </Batch>
  </XML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract values of an attribute use `elt.getAttribute("attribute_name")`, for example:

```
print(sym.getAttribute("afg"), sym.getAttribute("ID"))
```

In your case `sym` is still a node list, not a node (tag), so you can access particular elements of the list like this, for example:

```
sym = ag.getElementsByTagName('Instrmt')
for e in sym:
    print e.getAttribute("afg")
```

Or just:

```
print sym[0].getAttribute("afg")
```

if you know there is only one element on the list.

You can check what your tag is with an expression like:

```
e.tagName == 'Instrmt'
```

Comment: I get this:    AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'

Comment: Thanks so interating over sym turns it into a tag?

Comment: Not exactly, your sym is a collection (list) of tags, whatever you get from `getElementsByTagName` is a list, even if it's just one element, so you must treat it as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) and [XPATH](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#xpath-support) specifications:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

data = '''\
<XML r="20030517" s="20042209" v="4.4" xr="FIA" xv="1">
- <Batch>
- <PosRpt RptID="175" BizDt="2013-01-03" ReqTyp="0" >
  <Pty ID="Ade" R="21" /> 
- <Pty ID="000" R="4">
  <Sub ID="F" Typ="29" /> 
  </Pty>
  <Instrmt afg="AG" ID="AG" Src="8" CFI="FFI" MMY="2013" Matf="2013"/> 
  <Qty Typ="AOD" QTYL="134" QTYS="0" /> 
  <Qty Typ="FIN" QTYL="149" QTYS="0" /> 
  <Amt Typ="FMTM" Amt="155065.44" /> 
  </PosRpt>
  </Batch>
  </XML>
'''

#tree = et.parse('test.xml')
tree = et.fromstring(data)

# Find the first Instrmt node anywhere in the tree
print(tree.find('.//Instrmt').attrib['afg'])

# Find a Qty node with a particular attribute.
print(tree.find(".//Qty[@Typ='FIN']").attrib['QTYL'])
```

Output:

```
AG
149
```